# does it make any sense to say "it would be considered as my own personal opinion" in the below sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

I'd like to know if the below sentence is meaningful to you?

> I don't want to do any review of the books **because that
> way, it would be considered as my own personal opinion.** the only way to figure out if the book is good or bad is to read it.

is the bold part correct?

Comment: Does it make sense? No.

Comment: It's wordy, to say the least...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to do any review of the books because that way, it would be considered as my own personal opinion. the only way to figure out if the book is good or bad is to read it.

For a weak interruption appearing mid-sentence, we either place a bracketing comma pair to separate it or do not place any comma at all.

With just the lone comma, as in the example, the interruption could be interpreted as the clause after it.

The interruption here is *that way* and I suggest a comma pair for it.

> I don't want to do any review of the books because[,] that way, it would be considered as my opinion.  [T]he only way to figure out if the book is good is to read it.

Redundant words *own personal* and *or bad* have been omitted.  To reduce wordiness, we could further omit that weak interruption.